# MySQL return min value but not null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table where there are columns students and grade obtained(A-F). A student can appear for test more than once. Sometimes students register but do not appear for test so the grade is not entered but student record entry is made.

I want to get best grade of each student. When I do min(grade) if there is any record with null, null gets selected instead of 'A-F' which indicate proper results. I want to get min of grade if grade exists or null if there are no grades.

```
SELECT `name`,min(grade) FROM `scores` group by `name`

Id | Name | Grade
1  | 1    | B
2  | 1    | 
3  | 1    | A
4  | 2    | C
5  | 2    | D
```

For name 1 it is fetching second record not the third one having 'A'.

Comment: The `min` function ignores `null`s, so if a student has a `null` value and a real grade, the grade will be shown - so something in your analysis must be wrong. Can you share some sample data and the exact query you're using? Another option is that it's a bug in your specific MySQL version. Can you share some details about it?

Comment: @Mureinik Its actually a empty field. My bad I said null. I have added the query and sample record in question

Comment: `Empty` meaning, a string without characters? Or `Null`, which actually means `no value`.

Comment: `Null` *is* no value. See [Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). An empty text is a value (except in some databases where it is Null). It's important to know the difference when you're working with databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the conversations in the comments, the easiest solution may be to convert your empty strings to `null`, and let the builtin `min` function do the heavy lifting:

```
ALTER TABLE scores MODIFY grade VARCHAR(1) NULL;

UPDATE scores
SET    grade = null
WHERE  grade = '';

SELECT   name, MIN(grade)
FROM     scores
GROUP BY name
```

If this is not possible, a dirty trick you could use is to have a `case` expression convert the empty string to a something you know will come after `F`:

```
SELECT   name, 
         MIN(CASE grade WHEN '' THEN 'DID NOT PARTICIPATE' ELSE grade END)
FROM     scores
GROUP BY name
```

And if you really need the empty string back, you can have another `case` expression around the `min`:

```
SELECT name, CASE best_grade WHEN 'HHH' THEN '' ELSE best_grade END
FROM   (SELECT   name, 
                 MIN(CASE grade WHEN '' THEN 'HHH' ELSE grade END) AS 
                   best_grade
        FROM     scores
        GROUP BY name) t
```

Comment: I tired the second method and it worked. But I am facing a problem. I have unique id for each record. When I run the query

SELECT   id,name, 
         MIN(CASE grade WHEN '' THEN 'DID NOT PARTICIPATE' ELSE grade END)
FROM     scores
GROUP BY name

I am getting results

Answer (score 0):

Change your query slightly to -

```
SELECT `name`,min(grade) FROM `scores` WHERE grade <> "" group by `name`
```

If the name has a grade/s assigned to it then the lowest will be returned else the resultset will be null

Comment: This will leave out students who registered but didn't take any exam.

Comment: That's correct, @Mureinik thanks for pointing it out. Well then maybe use 'Z' as the grade indicating students who registered but did not take the test and this way we ensure that if a grade exists then it will be returned as a min value and not null/empty